# Copy and overwrite one database into another using mysqldump differentially

Tags: mysql, database

I know that you can use the following command to copy a database from one SQL server to another and overwrite the database in the destination server.

```
$ mysqldump -u user --password=pass live_db_name | mysql -u user --password=pass -h localhost duplicate_db_name
```

However, I'm looking for a way to do this where it only does a differential copy.

*i.e. If anything is different in the destination database, it is modified to be identical to the source database.*

Does there exist an option using `mysqldump` to do this?

Comment: there's no facility in mysqldump to do that, no. if you are talking about changes to the database including schema changes (new tables, dropped tables, added indexes, added columns, changed column definitions) as well as data changes (updated rows, deleted rows).  As you note, we can do a full bore replacement, but mysqldump doesn't provide any functionality akin to producing a "differential change" script.

Comment: One of the most challenging problems you're likely to encounter in your programming career is one of "sync", of keeping two independent data sets synchronized. This happens all the time on either a micro level (e.g. game clients communicating their state with servers) or a more macro level (e.g. entire databases being reconciled) but the problems innumerable. There's no built-in tool to do this because the way in which conflicting changes are reconciled is highly subjective.

Comment: The simple way to do this is to set up replication. The hard way to do this is hard.

Comment: @tadman The model I'm working with, the destination database will never have modifications in it. I'm just trying to minify the data being pushed to it from the source database. This is a master to slave scenario, not a master to master scenario.

Comment: Replication is really the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option to do this with mysqldump.

Check out the Percona tools, or other MySQL tools, that might get you to the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: [`xtrabackup`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/index.html) has a differential backup method, but doing a restore requires an expensive operation to apply the diff to a complete backup and then restore that thing completely. There's no way to apply a partial backup.